# Changing folder's organization

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I'm trying to build my first node.js web-app. When I try to request the main page (placed into),

```
/home/nectarys/dev/nodejs/project/abc/server/partials/main/main.jade
```

I' get this error message, how do I fix it?

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "partials/[object Object]" in views
directory
"/home/nectarys/dev/nodejs/projects/abc/server/views"
    at Function.app.render (/home/nectarys/dev/nodejs/projects/abc/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:508:17)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (/home/nectarys/dev/nodejs/projects/abc/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:782:7)
    at Object.port [as handle] (/home/nectarys/dev/nodejs/projects/abc/server.js:52:9)
    at next_layer (/home/nectarys/dev/nodejs/projects/abc/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:103:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/nectarys/dev/nodejs/projects/abc/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:107:5)
    at /home/nectarys/dev/nodejs/projects/abc/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:213:24
    at Function.proto.process_params (/home/nectarys/dev/nodejs/projects/abc/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:286:12)
    at next (/home/nectarys/dev/nodejs/projects/abc/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:207:19)
    at SendStream.error (/home/nectarys/dev/nodejs/projects/abc/node_modules/express/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:87:37)
    at SendStream.emit (events.js:95:17) GET /partials/main/main 500 10.393 ms - 1253
```

Routes,

```
app.get('/partials/*', function (req, res){
    res.render('partials/' + req.params);
});

app.get('*', function (req, res){
    res.render('index');
});
```

Comment: req.params is a object as described here http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.params, it better to use http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.path in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You should tell nodejs to look at the first parameter and not the object.

Change

```
app.get('/partials/*', function (req, res){
    res.render('partials/' + req.params);
});
```

To

```
app.get('/partials/*', function (req, res){
    res.render('partials/' + req.params[0]);
});
```